# spliting string except in curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string on `","` but I don't want to split if `","` is in `"{}"`. There's no nested braces.

here is the string I want to split :

> EmbiBISupplierKPIResult_EditArea00001,EmbiBISupplierKPISearch,partyId=E10021&economicAreaPartyIds={DPP_20246, DPP_14726}&economicId={DPP_20246, DPP_14726}&requestedDateSearchType=ACTUAL_WEEK

Here is the result I expect :

```
EmbiBISupplierKPIResult_EditArea00001
EmbiBISupplierKPISearch
partyId=E10021&economicAreaPartyIds={DPP_20246, DPP_14726}&economicId={DPP_20246, DPP_14726}&requestedDateSearchType=ACTUAL_WEEK
```

Is there a regex to do this ?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it sounds like a push-down language rather than a regular language. If so, there probably isn't a regular expression solution to the problem possible.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you expect multiple level of nested braces or not ?

Comment: I would split on comma not followed by space.

Comment: @ Denys Séguret just one level

Comment: @FatalError i try many things but i'm not an expert in regex and i can't find any right solution....

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match` and be explicit about the optional matching of parts between braces:

```
var parts = s.match(/(\{[^{}]*\}|[^,{}]+)+/g)
```

```js
var s = 'EmbiBISupplierKPIResult_EditArea00001,EmbiBISupplierKPISearch,partyId=E10021&economicAreaPartyIds={DPP_20246, DPP_14726}&economicId={DPP_20246, DPP_14726}&requestedDateSearchType=ACTUAL_WEEK';

var parts = s.match(/(\{[^{}]*\}|[^,{}]+)+/g)

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(parts,null,'\t');
```

```html
<pre id=result></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
,(?=(?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*$)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL4tD3/3)

Comment: You shouldn't use this way for two main reasons. First,  for each comma, the string is parsed until the end (because of the lookahead) that makes the pattern inefficient. The other reason is that the fact that all curly brackets are closed is only an assumption.